# How can I able to act upon the APNS push message by taking an action contained in the payload

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, json, apple-push-notifications

I am new to objective-c, xcode and app dev so please bear this in mind.

I can send a push notification via APNS to my emerging app. I can see the JSON message and can NSSLog it.

```
Payload: {
    aps = {
        alert = {
            "action-loc-key" = Reveal;
            body = "Hi Aleem, we have a new special offer just for you!";
        };
        badge = 70;
        sound = default;
    };

    myCMD = {
        "update_colour" = red;
    };
}
```

All good so far. However, I need to be able to act upon the push message by taking an action. For example, I want to be able to extract the `update_colour` and use the value red to change the background colour of a label on my one and only controller to red.

My problem is that I cannot reference my label from my appdelegate.m. Therefore I can't update the background colour or even call a method on the controller to do it either.

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: Appstore review guidelines, point 5.6 re: advertising or marketing push notifications ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your delegate add:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

Then when a push notification is received whilst the application is running/ a user opens a push notification you can access the notifications payload and act upon it, you could then send a notification to your view controller.

Add the Observer, in your view:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(backgroundChanged:)
                                         name:@"ChangeBackground"
                                       object:nil];
```

Add handle it.

```
- (void)backgroundChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];

    NSLog(@"%@" [[dict valueForKey:@"myCMD"] valueForKey:@"background-colour"]);

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor xxx];
}
```

Then in the delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    if([userInfo valueForKey:@"myCMD"]) {
            NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"ChangeBackground"
                                    object:nil
                                    userInfo:userInfo];
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks,Sorry I'm new to objective c. Which files do I add the Observer and Handler to?

Comment: Add the observer to the View Controller, where you want the background to change in -viewDidLoad, also in the view controller add the -backgroundChanged: where you handle the actual change of your label. Then in the delegate you listen for the APN and send the notification to the ViewController.

Comment: Excellent, getting my head around notificationCenter was the key. Many many thanks!!